# NSJSONSerialization error. Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0

Tags: swift

`NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` error when using a string like "abc" but success using "123"

I do not know why.

---

**error log**

```
2015-11-04 17:42:02.997 SwiftJsonDemo[27196:2701028] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

---

**code**

```
//var str = "123" // ok
var str = "abc" // error
let strData = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

if let d = strData {
    let urlStr = String(data: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(d, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
    } catch let e {
        print(e)
    }
} else {
    print("data error")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
123
```

is a valid JSON number, so this can be read as JSON if the `.AllowFragments`
option is set. JSON strings *must* be enclosed in quotation marks:
(see http://www.json.org for the details):

```
"abc"
```

In a Swift string literal, these quotation marks are escaped with
backslashes:

```
let str = "\"abc\"" // OK!
let strData = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Got it!

Answer (score 4):

Check with following line of code if using swift:

```
let contentType = response.response?.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"] as? String
```

Content type will be not coming as: "application/json". It implies response from server is not a valid JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Response in Postman. i just solved by checking if json response is proper format or in html format

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Turns out the mistake is in the request. The below syntax fixed the problem while adding parameters to the request.

```
request.setValue("Value", forHTTPHeaderField: "Key")
```