# Alamofire custom parameters

Tags: ios, swift, curl, alamofire

I am trying to convert this curl call to Alamofire in Swift.

```
 curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download    
     --header "Authorization: Bearer ab-xxx-x-x"     
     --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": "/acme101/acmeX100/acmeX100.001.png\"}"
```

And I figured this ...

```
let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer " + token2Save]
let moreheaders:Parameters = ["Dropbox-API-Arg": ["path":sourcePath]]

Alamofire.request("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download", parameters: moreheaders, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: headers).responseJSON { feedback in
        guard feedback.result.value != nil else {
            print("Error: did not receive data", print("request \(request) feedback \(feedback)"))
            return
        }
```

But of course it doesn't work, it crashes with ...

```
request (Function) feedback FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
Error: did not receive data ()
```

This needs to be in the header, not the body.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518839/nsjsonserialization-error-code-3840-invalid-value-around-character-0

Comment: Expected result is in which format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355850/alamofire-invalid-value-around-character-0

Comment: Thanks UB, you were right on the mark; although my problem is unsolved, needed to use responseData at which point it tells me I haven't encoded the correct parameters!! will resubmit the question....

Answer (score 3):

```
let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer " + token2Save]
let moreheaders:Parameters = ["Dropbox-API-Arg": ["path":sourcePath]]

Alamofire.request("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download", parameters: moreheaders, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: headers).responseJSON { feedback in
        guard feedback.result.value != nil else {
            print("Error: did not receive data", print("request \(request) feedback \(feedback)"))
            return
```

*URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: headers).responseJSON*

> Replace responseJSON with responseString and check your response  from webservice.. it will lead to get the error line.