# Issue with uploading an image using Alamofire(has image as a parameter)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

This is how I am trying to upload an image using Alamofire. But the program crashes saying something like...`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...` I'm not able figure the exact reason.This is how I'm making the request...

```
    for i in 1...(imageArray.count) {
        for img in imageArray {

            let url = "http://myapp.com/a/images_upload"
            let headers = [ "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

  let imageData: Data = (UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.6) as Data?)!
            print(imageData)

            let parameters: [String: Any]  = [
                    "access_token":  commonVarForAccessToken,
                    "seller_id": idForNewOldUser, 
                    "product_id": self.productId,
                    "is_default": "1",
                    "sequence": i,
                    "image": imageData  ]

            Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                print(parameters)

                multipartFormData.append(imageData as Data, withName: "home-\(self.index)", fileName: "home-\(self.index)", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

                for (key, value) in parameters {
                    print(key,value)

                    multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)

                }
            }, to:url)
            { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                        //Print progress
                    })
                    upload.responseJSON { response in

                        print(response.request)  // original URL request

                         if let JSON = response.result.value {
                            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                        }

                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):

                    print(encodingError)
                    break
                }}}}
```

Hope somebody can help...Thanks...:)

Comment: why use two times loop?

Comment: Somewhere there is a (inner/hidden) call to `dataUsingEncoding:` which doesn't work because the object is a `(NS)Number` but not a `(NS)Data`. I'd say it's that line: `multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)`. You can't do `((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)` on any kind of class of `value`. I don't know what are the class of the other objects, but `"sequence": i,` should crash it.

Comment: I also tried giving the sequence a hardcoded value of "1" but then again it crashes maybe it is not accepting the image in the given format...The imageData is just shown as '403829 bytes'...could this be an issue, @Larme ?

Comment: the loop is used twice, @AsaduzzamanShuvro because sequence has the number of images taken from the gallery and the other loop iterates through  each of the images picked...

Comment: use my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651187/upload-photo-file-with-json-and-custom-headers-via-swift-3-and-alamofire-4-i/46116478#46116478 just pass image like dict.set(imgview.image, forKey:"upload1") and if you are not uploading video then pass nil as parameter @User.bw

Comment: In your answer, @JitendraModi what is webservice in self.webservice...?

Comment: it is object of this class WebServiceHandler. just declare like as let webservice = WebServiceHandler()

Comment: Ok..I'll see...

Comment: was trying your code @JitendraModi..but a bit confused as to how I can use my parameters in your code...can you just help with that maybe....?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code.It's working for me.

```
let para: [String: Any]

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: {(multipartFormData) in

for i in 0..<uploadImages.count{         multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadImages[i], 0.3)!, withName: "image\(i)", fileName: "swift_file\(i).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpg")             
        }

        for (key, value ) in para {
            multipartFormData.append((value).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
    }, to: apiURL)
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _,_ ):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                UILabel().text = "\((progress.fractionCompleted * 100)) %"
                print (progress.fractionCompleted * 100)
            })


            upload.responseJSON { response in

                guard ((response.result.value) != nil) else{
            print(response.result.error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
```