# Crash while uploading an image using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

This is how I'm trying to upload an image from my phone gallery using Alamofire...

```
func uploadTheImg() {
    var i = Int()
        i = 0
        for img in imageArray {
            let url = "http://myUrl…"
            let headers = [ "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

        let imageData: Data = (UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.6) as Data?)!

        i = i+1
        let parameters: [String: Any]  =
            [
                "seller_id": “263”,
                "is_default": "1",
                "sequence": "\(i)", //This specifies the no.of images picked from the phone gallery
                "image": imageData // This is each of the image in the array.
                "access_token": “4c10c1f41e2cfddb146fd54e871890e2”,
        ]
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: {(multipartFormData) in
            let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)

            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

            for (key, value ) in parameters {
                print(key,value)
                multipartFormData.append(((value) as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII.rawValue)!, withName: key)   //CRASHES HERE
            }
        }, to: url)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, , ):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    UILabel().text = "\((progress.fractionCompleted * 100)) %"
                    print (progress.fractionCompleted * 100)
                })
                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    guard ((response.result.value) != nil) else{
                        print(response.result.error!.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                break
            }}}}
```

But in this part... `multipartFormData.append(((value) as AnyObject...` the for loop prints the keys and values of the `"seller_id","is_default","sequence","image"` and then it suddenly crashes without printing the access token. Don't know what is causing this crash...

Any help is appreciated..Thanks...

Comment: Same issue as before (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661121/issue-with-uploading-an-image-using-alamofirehas-image-as-a-parameter#comment80271218_46661121). `multipartFormData.append(((value) as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII.rawValue)!, withName: key) ` will crash because when it hits `"image": imageData`, `imageData` is a `Data` object, so it doesn't responds to `data(using:)` in fact, it doesn't needs it it's already a Data object! And there should be a crash log expliciting clearly that this is the error.

Comment: Also, since you already do `ultipartFormData.append(imageData,...)` remove `"image": imageData` from the `parameters`.

Comment: Ok @Larme..so you are saying that even though "image": imageData was a parameter that was supposed to be given, since we have multipartFormData.append(imageData,...), we need not specify imageData as a parameter in the list of Parameters...?

Comment: Just remove it because in your code you are adding `imageData` twice, and the second times it's badly done and causes a crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try replace  `multipartFormData.append(((value) as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII.rawValue)!, withName: key)` with `multiData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)`. 
Hope it helps you

Comment: @bws Note that in this answer, NSString is not being used. A standard Swift String is being used

Comment: You try convert your parameters to type [String: String]. 
I believe it will work

Comment: Ok...so you are saaying that instead of [String:Any] in the parameters, it should be [String: String...?]

Comment: But doing this also gives an error because the imageData that is passed is of type 'Data'..the error message given is..."Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected dictionary value type 'String' "

Comment: Please remove image: imageData in your parameters. And do this with your [UIImage] array: for image in arrayImages { if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation (image, 0.2) { print (imageData) multiData.append (imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image / jpg") } } } }

Comment: Then convert your parameters to [String: String] and: for (key, value) in parameters { multiData.append (value.data (using: .utf8) !, withName: key)

Comment: Have you finished your work yet? If it seems puzzling I will send you see the code I wrote

Comment: Thanks @Hai Nguyen..it seems it's working fine because I can get the upload progress in the success switch case. But there's a small concern...the control is not going into this block....'upload.responseJSON { response in' Any idea as to why this is happening..? Does it mean anything like the operation has not happened successfully...?

Comment: If you have already obtained the upload progress, you have successfully sent multipartFormData to the server. Your problem, you try check your API again

Comment: ok..and does sending multipartFormData to the server mean the image has been uploaded  to the server...?

Comment: When you print progress.fractionCompleted. That means you have uploaded multipartFormData successfully. As for the problem at "'upload.responseJSON {response in" you try check your API. Do you understand ?

Comment: Ok. @Hai Nguyen

Comment: The API seems to be fine @Hai Nguyen ...any idea as to what else could be the issue...?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this way

let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.5)!

```
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "pictureData",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")}
```